# VB6 Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: vb6

```
Function Test() As Boolean
  Dim objT As New Testing.Test
  objT.SetDataSource .....
  Test = objT.ValueExistInTable(CLng(1))
  Set objT = Nothing
End Function
```

Object variable or With block variable not set

ValueExistInTable is in a different dll.  When I call ValueExistInTable directly from the webpage, it works correctly returning a boolean value.

I'm not sure where I am going wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at what you are passing to your SetDataSource just to make sure that is something if it is an object.  Try renaming your funtion Test to something else like Test1, it could be getting confused with the name of the function and the name of the object Test.

Comment: The other one to try if changing the name doesn't work, is to put a break point on objT.SetDataSource, then you can step through it and see where it throws the error.